# warning LNK4217 and error LNK2022

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

I am getting a linker warning

`warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol lzma_check_is_supported imported in function "void __cdecl parse_real(struct args_info *,int,char * *)" (?parse_real@@YAXPAUargs_info@@HPAPAD@Z)`

`lzma_check_is_supported` function is present in some other .cpp file in another directory. `parse_real` is present in different one. I have given the path `-I../src/common` (which contains the definition of this function) while compiling the source code. However, it doesn't seem to work and the application crashes.

Also, if I paste the code of `lzma_check_is_supported` in the file containing `parse_real` the app crashes, but this time the crash takes place a little further(saw this in windbg).

I am guessing that the function definition is not available to the linker and hence it might be importing. At first, I ignored this warning but then I figured out that this was the main issue.

MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa3se25k(v=vs.80).aspx says compile with `/clr`. But then I get `error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types (types: lzma_coder_s; fields: <alignment member>): (0x04000003).`

I referred other posts which said to delete the debug folder and re-build(doesn't work). I only want to resolve the linker warnings. Am I doing it right by compiling with `/clr` flag?

If yes, then how do I go about fixing metadata errors?

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't guess, or pay attention to posts which might be only slightly related to your actual problem. I would start again and attempt to actually understand the compilation and linking process on Windows. Sorry I can't help more but there's not enough information in your post to answer you question. I would need to see full details of your project. It probably quite simple, if it's getting too complex you are probably doing it wrong.

Comment: @john Ok. first things first. How do I resolve `warning LNK4217`? Compiling with `/clr` isn't solving the problem

Comment: I can't think of any reason compiling with /clr would fix it and I don't think the page you link to says that it would. As I said you have to **understand** what these errors mean. In the case of LNK4217 it is because you are both importing and defining locally the same symbol. So the way to fix it is not to do that. Since I can't see your project I can't tell how you've got it into that state. That's why my advice would be to start again. Whatever you've done wrong maybe you won't do it if you start from scratch.